# Cloud9からLambdaコードをローカル実行するには

Tags: aws, aws-lambda

Cloud9からNode.jsで実装されたLambda関数をローカルで実行しようとしたのですが上手く行きません。
具体的には、画面上部メニューから「Run」を押すとLambda実行用画面(「Test Payload」「Execution Result」が表示される画面)が表示されることを期待したのですが、
実際には、下記のキャプチャのように通常の実行画面が表示され、RunnerがNode.jsで実行されてしまいます。
Lambdaとして実行するにはどのように操作すればよいでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

Lambda 関数を Cloud9 にインポートしたあと、対象の関数を右クリックして Run Local で実行するのではないでしょうか。
以下のドキュメントの「Lambda 関数を呼び出す」に画面キャプチャがあります。

- AWS Cloud9 Integrated Development Environment (IDE) で AWS Lambda 関数を操作する - AWS Cloud9 
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/cloud9/latest/user-guide/lambda-functions.html